# How can I "zebra stripe" CSS columns?

Tags: css, multiple-columns, zebra-striping

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="mycolumns">
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    ...
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS (assume prefixes):

```
.mycolumns {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

How can I "zebra stripe" the odd **columns**? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/DV875/) with what I assumed would be correct (note I'm using SCSS for my CSS)

Comment: I looked around and it seems like you cannot target the columns via a pseudo-selector, even on Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't do it with CSS, jQuery can always help you.

You can use the [jQuery Columnizer Plugin](https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin/) to perform the same task, but since it wraps the columns in actual elements, you can target the individual columns via CSS:

```
.column:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 200, 200);
}
```

Comment: ...meh. while this would work if i absolutely needed it to, i'm looking for a css solution. i can accept the fact that there is none if that's indeed the case.